# Visual Studio 2015 RC Community will not install, says it is already installed

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

As the title implies, I am not able to install Visual Studio 2015 RC Community, and I keep getting the following errors. For the record, I am on Windows 8.1 Professional.

1. Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 is currently installed on this machine. Please uninstall Visual Studio 2015 and retry.
2. Visual Studio Professional 2015 is currently installed on this machine. Please uninstall Visual Studio 2015 and retry.

I would have provided the screenshot, but it would seem I have to have certain amount of reputation to do so. Sorry!

Pretty straightforward messages; just uninstall Visual Studio 2015. The only problem is that I uninstalled it a few months back. I have already made sure to manually remove anything and everything I could find regarding Visual Studio on my computer including performing a forced uninstall of Visual Studio and manually deleting the Visual Studio files from the Program Files directories.

Does anyone have any further tips on what to do next? I am at a loss at this point. And feel free to ask any questions that you feel may help with this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you try to install, are you given the option to repair or modify the installation?

Comment: Try starting the installer with the `/uninstall /force` option to see if that'll work. You'll need the installer of the version you have installed, finding it may be difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: @SteveFerg, I am not given any options to repair or modify the installation, unfortunately. It goes straight to that message.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I have tried that with all the versions mentioned, and with the community version as well. All of them executed properly and supposedly uninstalled, but I still get that same message.

Comment: With versions I did not mean the different editions, but the preview 1, preview 2 and the release candidate. And any other builds you might have tried.

Comment: I remember having tried preview 1 or 2, though I can't remember which for the life of me. I gave up though and ended up just reinstalling Windows. Frustrating, but it is done.

Comment: One thing to check, don't have any 2014 versions installed either. I had a CTP of 2014 Ultimate that I'd forgotten all about. Removing it fixed the false 2015 flag.

Answer (score 39):

I had a similiar issue and found finally as cause entries under

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0.
To modify/delete this entries (or the key itself) solved (for me) the problem.

By K.Hoffmann

Comment: I didn't want to touch the registry, but as a last resort I backed it up, and removed this key. The installer worked for me after.

Comment: You just saved me from wasting another 3 days on this. Thanks :)

Comment: On Windows 7 32-bit, look under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing and delete the 14.0 key.

Comment: Thank you! this simple tip has helped me better than Microsoft itself did! In my case, i had the RC of Visual Studio 2015 installed and wanted to install Visual Studio 2015 Community. I tried to uninstall 2015 enterprise RC, (even with the /uninstall /force) but the installer of Visual studio 2015 kept blocking saying i needed to uninstall the enterprise version. Deleting the key above fixed it for me!

Comment: This simple tip worked even for VS Community 2015 Update 3 issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

OK, all else fails, then do it the hard way. First off, backup your system, just in case, make two backups. **Warning:** *Running the Registry Editor can be a good way to blow your system out of the water if you are not careful.* In addition there are many Google pages out there that outline variations for this theme. Visual Studio though seems to have its tendrils everywhere in the registry. First, the easier way:

1. Click **Start**, and then click **Run**.
2. In the **Open** box, type **regedt32**, and then click **OK**.
3. under **File -> export**, save the registry file where **Export range** has **All** checked.
4. In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
5. Each key listed under **Uninstall** in the left pane of Registry Editor represents a program that is displayed in the **Currently installed programs** list of the Add or Remove Programs tool. To determine which program that each key represents, click the key, and then view the following values in the details pane on the right:

   DisplayName: The value data for the DisplayName key is the name that is listed in Add or Remove Programs.
   -and-
   UninstallString: The value data for the UninstallString key is the program that is used to uninstall the program. (You can try the uninstall string manually if you like, but it may not work since you said you have deleted everything.)
6. After you identify the registry key that represents the program that you removed but which is still displayed in the Currently installed programs list of Add or Remove Programs, right-click the key in the left pane of the Registry Editor window, and then click Delete. This assumes that it appears in **Programs and Features** if not, then ignore the rest of these steps.
7. Click **Yes** in response to the "Are you sure you want to delete this key and all of its subkeys?" message.
8. On the **File** menu, click Exit to quit Registry Editor.
   Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click **Programs and Features**.

Verify that the program whose registry key you deleted is no longer listed.
Reboot and try the install again.

> If it still does not work, then do it the really hard way

Go back into `regedt32` and then do a find and delete all keys that have

> Visual Studio 2015

or

> Visual Studio 14.0

If it says Visual Studio with a revision number less than 14.0, then leave it alone. If in doubt, then leave it alone, you can always do another pass. Sometimes it can take more than one pass to find everything. It will take a while to find and delete all the associated keys, and is very tedious. Once complete, cross your fingers and reboot your system and try the install again.

*These steps, from experience, have worked for me, so I am not telling you anything that I have not tried myself (the hard way).*

Comment: Well, I just tried both of those steps, and unfortunately neither one seems to have resolved the issue. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Well, I was sure that would work since it did for me ... wow thats frustrating... next thing is a little more drastic. If you reinstall windows, you should be able to do a repair, which should retain all your programs and settings. The problem is that it is no guarantee, considering the regedt fix did not work.

Comment: Yeah, I am considering just backing up my data and reinstalling Windows. Not a perfect fix, but it could work. I guess it is just a matter of just how important it is to me, right?

Comment: I've been there. More than once. I wish I had a better answer for you.

Comment: Eh, it happens every now and then. Thank you for helping though as much as you could.

Answer (score 3):

What helped in my case was to click the little blue 'show log' link.

In the log, there were like 360 lines, but the most important was this:

```
[1184:1BEC][2015-10-15T16:31:26]i102: Detected related bundle: {5c2b89b0-08cc-492f-b086-21e4d6ae7be4}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.0.23107.10, operation: None
```

So I searched the registry (see @SteveFerg's answer for how best to do it) for the key **5c2b89b0-08cc-492f-b086-21e4d6ae7be4** which was stated in the log line. Then I deleted all corresponding keys (mainly in *Dependent* branches, but importantly in the *Uninstall* branch).

That solved the problem in my case without scouring the whole registry for hours for every *Vistual Studio* entry.

Answer (score 3):

Found this tool that forcefully uninstalls everything related to Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. It did the trick for me.

[VisualStudioUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps from [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c20e1e9-4322-4f83-94d1-588f5cf2b77a/problem-with-visual-studio-community-instalation?forum=vssetup) to uninstall the VS2015 Ultimate and VS2015 Preview by running the command

```
D:\vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force
```

*(replace D with the VS2015 DVD or mounted ISO drive letter)*

The forum says for VS2013 but same method will work for uninstalling any edition.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing a similar problem (trying to get rid of Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate CTP and install Visual Studio 2015 Professional instead). I had troubles uninstalling the CTP and the Professional edition kept complaining that the Ultimate version is already installed. Unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions worked for me (forced uninstall, TotalUninstall, MS Install and Uninstall diagcab, no DevDiv registry key...).
But I finally found a solution suitable for my case - using [msiinv utility](https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=27e6a35d1a492af7&resid=27E6A35D1A492AF7!910&parId=27E6A35D1A492AF7!376&authkey=!ANs8Pr0aVhaT_qQ).

> The msiinv tool is a tool which will list all installed msi on your OS. In that way you can check them and if you want to remove any of them, you may try the msiexec /x  to remove that component.

Basically all that needed to be done is described in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer/):

> 1) Extract the contents of msiinv.zip to the folder `c:\msiinv` on your system
>       2) Click on the Start menu, choose Run, type `cmd` and click OK
>       3) Type this command:  `c:\msiinv\msiinv.exe -p > c:\msiinv\msiinv_output.txt`
>       Note: This command must be run from a cmd prompt or it will not create a log file as expected.
>       These steps will create a text file named `c:\msiinv\msiinv_output.txt`
>       with a list of each product that Windows Installer thinks is installed
>       on the system.  Then you can open the text file in any text editor and 
>       search the list of products for the name of the product that setup told
>       you to uninstall.  
>       In the output there should be a part looking like this *(changed to VS2015 Ultimate)*:
>
> ```
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate CTP
>       Product code: {EF2A2E8D-E03C-370E-810F-449BECDE2240}
>       Product state: (5) Installed.
>       Package code: {another GUID here}
>       Version: 14.0(...)
> ```
>
> Now we have the Windows Installer product code and we can use that to uninstall the product by running `msiexec /x <product code>` (make sure that you include the curly braces in this command line).  If the product is actually installed on your system you will see a progress screen and uninstall will complete.

I have repeated the steps also for `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate CTP - ENU`, just to be sure.
The Professional edition installer then launched and finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by more or less following this post. I previous installed VS 2015 on my partition which I accidentally formatted without uninstalling and was giving me the same error.

So I had to manually hand delete many references in both the 32 and 64 bit registry.

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head over uninstalling 2015 RC for hours.  I found quite a few discussions about uninstalling RC but nothing worked.

I used variations of  vs_*.exe /uninstall /force but nothing worked.

I do not remember, but I think I must have performed an "online" install of RC and found a file with the same filedate as the install date.

The following worked for me: vns_full.exe /uninstall /force

Thanks to all the people in all the forums that eventually helped me find a solution to this uninstall RC problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue then installing update1 to the visual studio 2015 community.

[install error, link to the image and text:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhSi0.png)

> Visual Studio Professional 2015 is currently installed on this
>   machine. Please uninstall Visual Studio Professional 2015 and retry.

In past i installed plugin *Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects* that didn't work with VS 2015 community and work with VS 2015 profession.

This recipe was:

1) Launch RegEdit

2) if win32:
    Select key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0"
    if win64:
    Select key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0"

3) In that key/subkey, you must create two new subkeys:
    "professional"
    "vscore"

4) In each of the subkeys you have just created create a REGSZ value (=string) with the name "Install" and value "1" (yes: "1" is a string!)

**Now to address the problem in VS 2015 community had to rename or delete a folder in the registry "professional"**

[Before community folder, picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAFUL.png)

[Before professional folder, picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hJYD.png)

[vscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n46lP.png)

[After professional folder, picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRNbU.png)

Answer (score 0):

When VS 2015 community edition fails to install normally (That's without errors), the most probable reason is the presence of a virus or malware on the system.
I had this issue earlier but managed to solve it by installing Symantec end point protection.
After cleaning the malware and viruses, I managed to install VS 2015 Community successfully.
Hope that's help.

Answer (score -1):

After updating the anti-virus (McAfee), I successfully installed it.