# Visual Studio 2015 RC Community says This license has expired

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I originally had Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise CTP and it's expired. I uninstalled it and installed Visual Studio 2015 RC Community. However, it still says "This license has expired" (and any attempt to sign in fails as I don't have MSDN subscription). I uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 RC Community with /force command-line switch, removed all VSCommon, VisualStudio and Visual Studio disk folders and registry entries, and also Licenses registry subbranches requested by Visual Studio during startup (accordingly sysinternal's Process Monitor), and then reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 RC Community. I also run devenv.exe /resetuserdata (normally and under Administrator) with no luck. I'm running Windows 7 x64 if this matters.

It keeps telling "This license has expired". "Check for an updated license" tries to sign me in with no luck. Signing in with my Live.com account doesn't work (again, only MSDN subscription would suffice there). How else can I make Visual Studio "forget" that I previously had Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise CTP?

Is reinstalling the OS the only solution?

Unlike possible duplicate, I focus here on exact errors which are happening.

Comment: This is not related to programming

Comment: Yes, but I first checked that similar questions are widely present on SO, that's why I decided to put it there. For instance (not exactly my case, but close to it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080698/visual-studio-2015-rc-community-will-not-install-says-it-is-already-installed If you feel it's wrong place to post, could you please recommend a better one? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same license expired issue, only I was already using the Community edition. Trying to figure out why that one expired or how to keep using it for now!

Comment: you could try allowing it through the firewall like I did here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33765402/2308533

Comment: As I said on 23 Jul in my comment to @jmcrick, the upgrade to RTM version has solved the issue for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [License expired after installation Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537812/license-expired-after-installation-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-community)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that IE8 was the problem. Once I updated to IE11, signing to Live.com finally worked. So, the core of the problem was IE version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple repair?  Control Panel - Programs and Features - Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 - Change - Repair.

Comment: Yes, I did. Now RTM version is here so the issue is no longer important to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried uninstall and didn't work. Before going to registry manipulations, tried this:

Close the IDE, go and create your Visual Studio **Online** free account.
(https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs - hope the link works)
Open IDE, and click "Check for updated license".

Login with that account, and hopefully this will work, as with my VS - 
"License downloaded successfully".