# License expired after installation Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community. After installation an signing in I'm getting error:
License: Prerelease license.

This license has expired.

I cannot do anything!

Can somebody help me?

I downloaded today installer from:

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

Comment: Same problem here. Fresh install of VS2015 Community (no previous beta/rc's installed). I'm going to try to repair from iso.

Answer (score 25):

I had this same problem. The Community Edition is free, but you have to sign into your Microsoft account to use it more than 30 days. Go to "https://account.microsoft.com/about" and signup for an account. It's free. When you complete the process, you can sign into Visual Studio using the same email address.

Comment: It's free if you provide your e-mail address and your phone number. No, thank you.

Comment: Just did this -- only had to create a new account providing just an email address. Phone number was not required.

Answer (score 9):

I had to **reset Visual Studio's settings** totally with:

```
Devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

After that my license was detected correctly.

See **[this post on MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/5b4ae664-1535-48c5-8f49-d7d1e0a7b374/#f4788aa1-a567-46d3-b14a-f4b5d5acbaed) for more details**

Comment: As mentioned at the [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/5b4ae664-1535-48c5-8f49-d7d1e0a7b374/#f4788aa1-a567-46d3-b14a-f4b5d5acbaed) `/resetuserdata` worked for me. (Actually, I did twice: once from the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015, then again from an Administrator Command Prompt.)

Comment: Had to Win+R Devenv.exe /ResetSettings 2 times then it said Cannot save downloaded license file so I gived VS2015 Administrator rights

Comment: In VS 2017 `/ResetSettings` didn't worked but `/resetuserdata` fixed the problem.
Unfortunately one of them uninstalled/broke all non MS extensions so I had to reinstall them.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem using the small executable. I downloaded the .ISO and installed from that. Had no problems since.

Comment: How do you "repair from Iso"? I had a failed setup first, so I did vs_community.exe /layout to download it, then tried reinstalling. It went through the entire setup again. Now when I start it, it immediately exits telling me the license has expired?

Comment: I have been having the same problem with the enterprise RTM version (we have a full license for MSDN enterprise). I have uninstalled and reinstalled, and am about to throw in the towel with 2015.

Comment: I installed from web installer (vs_community.exe). After a failed install (first time) I restarted PC and started the install again. It installed succesfully, but wouldn't start with the 'license expired' message.
I then downloaded the iso. Started the installer from iso, it said the product is already installed, so I choose 'Repair'. Once more machine restart and everything works now.

Comment: I went to Control Panel | Programs and Features, selected Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, selected change, then Repair. That worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

After scouring the web and trying just about anything I came I cross with no success, I managed to get the darned thing working. Here’s what worked for me perhaps it will help others as well.

```
1. From the top menu in VS select  Tools>options>web browsers
2. Click the “Select Internet Explorer options” button
3. Select the Security tab at the top
4. Click Trusted sites 
5. Click the Sites button
6. Add https://*.visualstudio.com 
7. Close the options window until you’re back to the VS IDE
8. From the help menu select “Register product”
9. If already signed in click the “Check for an updated license” else login first.
```

That should do it, if not try the option step as well. 
OPTIONAL if that fails repeat the steps above but on step 6 add https://*. technet.microsoft.com

Good luck.

Comment: This was the only process that fixed my install of VS 2015 Community.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today and solved as follows:

There are two links on page the page which tells you your license has expired.

1. Add Account: Click here and add (or create) your Microsoft account.
2. Check for updated license(or similar): Click on it and provide the same account credentials.

This should update the license.

Answer (score 1):

I initially had the same issue as described above.  When I logged in with my normally-valid account, I got 'Failed to download new licence'.  We have a proxy server that requires credentials for some things: a clue is that I see an 'Enter credentials' button beneath the 'Featured Videos' column on the VS Start Page.  After I'd clicked that button and entered my proxy credentials, I went back to the account settings page and checked for an updated licence and it downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to logout from the Visual Studio account (in VS2015) first, then log back in again. That resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that hitting "check licence" didn't work after entering the trusted sites into IE (I added the technet and visual studio full domains as mentioned by Rob above) .

***However***, after I signed out and back in again with my MS account in Visual Studio it updated my licence automatically without having to manually check for it.

Simple fix but easily overlooked so thought I would mention it.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by getting a Microsoft account at http://www.microsoft.com  and sign in from Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

I also had a problem of getting a community licence. 
The reason was, that I logged to MS account using the Firefox.
I realised, that MS VC++ tries to log to this account using the 
Internet Explorer (IE). 
So I tried to log there (manually) using IE, and then it told
me that it is impossible, because cookies are not allowed by my
IE. Then I went to "options" and enabled all cookies.
Then I succesfully logged to MS account. 
Then I started MS VC++ ad when I asked to get an updated licence - it showed me a logging dialog. I was able to log, and then I got a licence.
Hurra!  (but it took me more than month to solve this problem. Lucky: this web page was an inspiration. Thank you!).

Answer (score -1):

**No, Community edition is free to use.**
So when you see the dialogue box... find Link **Click for an updated license** and processed for the sign in with your Microsoft account... If you are not register then [SignUp Now](https://signup.live.com/).... and complete the process...

[Solution Reference URL Which was provided by microsoft](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/community-edition-expired-buy-license/)