# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition failed to download new license

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I recently uninstalled VS 2013 & 2015 from my system. I uninstalled every bit I could find that said anything about VS. I then reinstalled it, default installation, everything went fine. Then on start up I get a splash screen that says my 30 day trial evaluation period has ended. I refresh my credentials, then click on the "Check for an updated license" and it says "Failed to download a new license." I know my username and password are fine because I can even Visual Studio profile online and create a team service project, which will even load up in VS 2015 but the splash screen still pops up and blocks me from touching anything else. Has anyone ever come across this and found a solution? I tried looking on past posts and they all say click on the "Check for an updated license" link, It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Visual Studio **Community Edition**?  That variant does not have a 30 day trial.

Comment: If you're talking about VS 2015 Professional, I had that issue in a VM once, so I uninstalled VS and .NET and reinstalled it and VS worked fine after that. If you're talking about VS 2015 Community Edition, it is free with no trial periods.

Comment: I also had this problem with the Community edition when I tried to sign in with my MSDN account. I tried change/repair from control panel, and also uninstall + reinstalling.  Eventually I installed the Professional edition instead and it worked fine. Makes sense to take the highest version I'm entitled to I suppose, but what a really useless error!

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete `%localappdata%\.IdentityService\SessionTokens.json`
3. Open Visual Studio, "Reenter credentials" and then "Check for an updated license"

Answer (score 1):

Run it as administrator. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, I think that there are a couple places to check:

- My problem was solved through this thread:
  [License expired after installation Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537812/license-expired-after-installation-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-community)
- System Date on your machine, sometimes if this is set incorrectly it can mess with the licensing.  This wasn't my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to log in to my account. Then, I was able to successfully download and update the license; otherwise it failed to download.