# Visual Studio professional 2015 trial period ended

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded and used the trial version of Visual studio professional 2015.

I would like to play around with the IDE for few more days before i actually buy the license.

Is there any way i can get the extended trial period for few more days without buying the license?

Also below screenshot shows to licence with an **online account** or product key.

But i am unable to extend the trail period with an new online account

[image]

Comment: Community Edition is free are you sure you are using a trial??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [License expired after installation Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537812/license-expired-after-installation-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-community)

Comment: Very sorry.. Its professional version 2015. I was reading lot of blogs and i wrote community in question. Anyway i edited now. Thanks a lot

Comment: I guess you should ask Microsoft

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks a lot. I corrected it now.

Comment: @NahuelIanni Thank you. I am looking for professional version only. I tried community version and professional both.

Comment: Use different email address? But, don't make a habit of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the [Visual Studio 2015 - Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) which provides almost the same functionality, development wise; as the professional edition. The main difference is related to advanced [TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/) features, but you can still check the IDE as much and for as long as you want, while also using TFS as a source control.

The community edition is free and allows you to build and publish the all kind of applications, unit test included.

You can check [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/) to see a comparison between the existing versions.

[image]

If you **need** to use the Professional version, you can try creating a new [Azure subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us) (it's free) and using the [free credits they give you](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/) on a monthly basis, create a virtual machine and use Visual Studio from there. Some VM templates already come with an installation of the IDE itself.

Comment: Thanks! Any luck to extend the trail version of professional by using another online account?

Comment: In order to use an online account, as far as I know, it must be tied to an MSDN subscription with access to VS 2015 Pro, which I assume it's not your case.

Comment: Right!  Azure sounds bit unsafe for critical projects. Although microsoft can be trusted to 100%, Not best option for me. But this option might help someone else here.

Comment: I downloaded community version and running my project. Happy days! Its looks all fine

Comment: Glad to hear :)