# I Get a message from Visual Studio: You are on day xxx of your 90 day evaluation period. Your trial period is expired! you must purchase

Tags: visual-studio

I get this message from time to time:

[image]

My Community version of VS seems to be registered correctly:

[image]

How can I find what component is sending me the message and how to avoid getting it?

Answer (score 0):

have you signed in?

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/community-edition-expired-buy-license

[License expired after installation Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537812/)