# Visual Studio doesn't authentificate me after I switch versions

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio (no matter if 2013 Professional, 2013 Community or 2015 Community, they all behave the same on different machines in different places and networks like home, office, friends' places) can't seem to access my login information and asks me to re-enter user and password. Here is a screenshot of the message, followed by a rough translation because I use the German version:

[image: The error message]

Translation: "An error occured, and no user information could be accessed for "[email address]". Re-enter your login information for this account. (Link: Re-enter login information)
(box with my correct live id)"

I haven't found a way to get any details about what error occured where and when or why, which doesn't help. Apparently it does save which account I use, but without re-entering my log-in at least once a day, functions that rely on it (e.g. accessing TFS repositories that my account has rights to) do not work. It seems to have some correlation to the time since I last logged in, because even after rebooting the machine it still works correctly if I logged in before.

It's not preventing me from work, but it's still very annoying. I've spent quite some time on google, but when I look for keywords like "visual studio login error" or similar fitting things I find all kinds of pages mainly about Visual Studio Online, or pages that explain how to login inside of Visual Studio - nothing mentions this problem, so I suppose it isn't a very common one.

My internet connection in all places is usually pretty stable, and no other open application show any signs of connection problems, so I can all but rule that out as the cause.

It took a while, but it seems to be a problem only when I switch versions of Visual Studio. I.e., if I only use 2013 for a while, it works fine. If I then login with 2015, I get the error when I use 2013 again after that, and vice versa.

Comment: Do you use the same email address to log into windows 10 by any chance? If you've changed your login password for windows, It also gets changed for microsoft related things like your hotmail address. I would presume that it would change for any logins linked to that email address when dealing with Microsoft

Comment: I do, but the problem already existed when I was using Windows 7. I didn't change the password either, and the problem re-appears every day or every few days or so (no real pattern there, I think), without changing anything.

Comment: Weird. Another Microsoft feature :-/

Comment: Microsoft has a habit of making amazing software and just adding a few bugs and idiosyncrasies that range from "somewhat annoying" like this to "borderline unusable in some use cases", that's nothing new to me. I'm just surprised that I can't find anybody else with the same problem, even though I got the same behaviour on two different versions of VS across three or four different machines with Win7, Win8(.1) and Win10. Maybe my account is somehow fubar, at least for use in VS?

Comment: If its on several different pcs, it might be a problem with your internet connection or your router? If VS is trying to refresh your profile data when the connection is down it might throw up this error. . There is quite a good site [here][1]. In the tools section, you can set up a monitor that checks your internet connection. It might highlight a problem you're unaware of.


  [1]: http://www.thinkbroadband.com

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue by allowing visual studio through the windows firewall, then restarting visual studio. It stems from parts of visual studio not having access to the authentication servers.

1. Press the windows key and search for "firewall" and select "allow a
   program through windows firewall
2. Click "Allow another program..."
3. Choose Visual Studio from the programs list and click add
4. Restart (or start) Visual studio

Comment: I'm quite sure VS is already allowed through the Firewall, but I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: after instruction above restart system is required. restart visual studio does not enough.