# Visual C++ 2015 Tools for Windows desktop installer won't open

Tags: c++, installation, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual studio 2015. But I didn't noitced that the typical install didn't include the c++ tools. I follewed this guide on the Visual C++ team blog(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/) but when I click on the install button only this window pops up.

[Pop up message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLfaD.png)

And after i press ok it closes and nothing happens(I have tried to run as administrator but nothing changes).

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio 2015 RC Community will not install, says it is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080698/visual-studio-2015-rc-community-will-not-install-says-it-is-already-installed)

I had a similiar issue and found finally as cause entries under
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0. To modify/delete this entries (or the key itself) solved (for me) the problem.